# How to add IntelliJ plugins to Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android, android-studio

Since Updating to Android Studio 3.6, I can't find my way to IntelliJ Plugins' Market place as previous versions used to have.

Any Ideas why is this? Or how to add plugins now?

The first img is for old plugins' preview, second one is for the 3.6's preview

[image: old android studio]

[image: new android studio]

Answer (score 1):

They are now in Preferences > Plugins.

Tip: if you can't find something on Android Studio, double press Shift and search for it (that's how I found where the plugins are)